# Why don't videos on my website appear on Google video search results?

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a couple of videos on my website which I'd like to be findable in the Google videos search results. The videos have been on this site for at least a month, so it's not that Google hasn't yet crawled them, it just doesn't consider them viable videos it seems.

However, they do seem to meet all their requirements (e.g. they have a thumbnail, title, description). Images and plain text on my website can be found via Google, the problem only exists with videos, so I figure I am doing something wrong with the syntax.

I'm currently using the HTML video tag for videos, and like to keep doing so. I don't really understand other stuff like sitemaps. I also don't use any third parties like YouTube for videos.

I've added some code snippets of different videos on my website.

[Video code example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCCXX.png)

[Video code example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noCRb.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Google is not showing your video because you might not have enough traffic on your website and the other websites with same title might have more traffic than yours so Google is showing their videos instead of your. To solve this increase traffic on your website and your video will be shown.

But you can try adding `<meta name="keywords" content="Virtual Reality, Cycling, Research and Development">` tag in `<head>` section  and insert as many keywords in `content` attribute separated by comma(,) to help search engine know more about your content and display it whenever required.

If you increase traffic it will give you more quick results than meta tag will.

If you have any doubt comment it and I will try my best to help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is it. I already have these tags in place on their respective pages (same page as the video). I have tags like keywords, author, description, abstract, etc. The thing is, even if I filter google videos with the syntax "site:www.mysite.com" (dummy address of course I don't wanna self-promote), it says there are no videos to be found

Comment: @JoepEijkemans Can you provide  URL of your website, it will help me to figure out what's the issue and solve your problem and even if i can't it would increase the traffic on your website and your video will be shown.

Comment: That'd be awesome. Here are the links to both pages I gave as an example. https://joepeijkemans.nl/Portfolio/Projects/Nyctophobia/  
  https://joepeijkemans.nl/Portfolio/Projects/VRcycling/  . I have more videos on different pages, but these 2 are the most popular in terms of both regular search and image search. PS: cool to see someone on stackoverflow so motivated to help

Comment: @JoepEijkemans I checked your website but can't resolve it but can you do me a favour that whenever you will find it's solution please comment and let me know how you did it. I would love to know how you resolved it. And I am really sorry for not solving your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I'll let you know once I solved it!

Comment: @JoepEijkemans  I wanted to know whether your issue was solved or not I am eagerly waiting to know how you solved it.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I haven't yet. I actually haven't really tried either, since it's not much of a priority for me at the moment. I'm planning to work on it today, however. If I fix it, I'll definitely let you know though. I won't know if it's fixed for a while though, since Google only indexes my site every once in a while, and I need that to happen to see if it's working now.

Comment: @JoepEijkemans Sad to hear it is not solved yet, but whenever it is solved please let me know.